# jQuery UI combo box empty value rendering

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, menuitem

I am using the customized combo box jquery ui widget (similar to this one http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

The problem is that items which have an empty value ("" or " ") render as following:

```
<li class="ui-widget-content ui-menu-divider"><a><strong></strong> <strong></strong></a></li>
```

instead of:

```
<li title="lib" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-36" tabindex="-1"><a><strong></strong>lstrong></strong>i<strong></strong>b<strong></strong></a></li>
```

this causes a divider to display in the list instead of a blank line.

My customized _renderItem looks like this:

```
input.data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                    return $("<li title='"+item.value+"'></li>").data("ui-autocomplete-item", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
                };
```

Where does jQuery change the empty value to display as a divider?
(might be worthwhile to note that this worked fine with an older version of jQuery (1.4.2) and jQuery UI (1.8.3) and stopped working now when trying to upgrade)

TIA!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this:
http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#method-_isDivider
So that is my answer...

This is how you would override the default _isDivider function used for the autocomplete's menu:

```
input.data("uiAutocomplete").menu._isDivider= function( item ) {
                      return false;
                }
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed this appears to be a better way than working around the regex.

Answer (score 6):

[Looking at this sourcefile](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js), line 6792 says

```
    this.menu = $( "<ul>" ).menu({...});
```

So, autocomplete is using the `ui.menu` widget internally. The menu widget, on the other hand, contains this in its `refresh` function (line 11727 in the same file):

```
    // Initialize unlinked menu-items containing spaces and/or dashes only as dividers
    menus.children( ":not(.ui-menu-item)" ).each(function() {
        var item = $( this );
        // hyphen, em dash, en dash
        if ( !/[^\-\u2014\u2013\s]/.test( item.text() ) ) {
            item.addClass( "ui-widget-content ui-menu-divider" );
        }
    });
```

So, easiest solution: add text which doesn't match that regex. I recommend the escape character `&#27;`:

```
... .append($("<a>").html("&#27;" + item.label))...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, indeed interesting, but I think that since the value is important to me I would prefer to try and use the _isDivider method somehow but I am getting a little stuck with the syntax: I would like to do something like this which doesn't work yet: input.data("uiAutocomplete").menu._isDivider: function( item ) {
                return false;
             }

Comment: Your reference in the jQuery code helped me use the solution below, thanks again

Comment: No probs, if you're going this way, however, I'd recommend extending [`_renderMenu`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderMenu) rather than the menu itself

Comment: I do already extend the _renderMenu, how would I use the _renderMenu to extend the _isDivider?